# Asus X540LJ laptop shuts down if I plug AC cable out

Tags: laptop, battery, power, asus-laptop

I have an Asus X540LJ laptop. I recently changed the battery: it is properly detected, and is charging if the AC cable is plugged in.

But my problem is: if the laptop is running, by unplugging the AC cable the laptop immediately shuts down; as well as the battery led is blinking orange!

I did a battery reset (by following steps on https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/asus-laptop-plugged-in-not-charging-solved/), the problem still persists.

If the AC cable is not plugged in, then I can't power on the laptop (by plugging AC cable in, power-on is possible).

What should I do? The battery is recognised, the driver is recent, the battery reset was done. But still no battery-mode, and the led is blinking orange.

Answer (score 1):

All the symptoms you described fit a weak battery, i.e. one that cannot provide the *current* needed by the device.

- Did you wait long enough to fully charge the battery before using it? This may take a day or more.
- Did the charge indicator change to green , showing the battery was fully charged? If not, then the charge regulator in the laptop may be faulty, or thew battery may be bad. To check, substitute another battery.

  - If that alternate battery works for some time and then **and can be recharged back to 100% in the laptop** after use, then it's certain the last battery was bad. *Easy fix:* change battery.
  - If the substitute battery works for a while, **but cannot be recharged in the laptop**, then the charging regulator in the laptop is defunct. *Harder fix:* the laptop would need to be taken apart and repaired.

Comment: Oh, no! As you write, it would be the charging regulator or something on the motherboard. Since the "battery-mode" does not work at all, even not for 1 second. It was from the begining so. The battery is recognized, but cannot be used or charged by the laptop.

Comment: @A.V., if it *never* worked, how do you know that it's *not* a dead battery???

Comment: this battery was tested with another laptop. Therefore!

Comment: Then you know that a *good* battery doesn't work, which shows it is not just the *charging* system that is broken, but the *internal power supply* that converts battery voltage to the various bus voltages is broken.